# How to fix ERROR (-1005)] ,problem with match statement without creating an index

Tags: nebula-graph

First I didn't create an index inside the graph space. I can get the result with `match ()-[e:follow]->() return e limit N` and `match ()-[e:follow]->(v) return e limit N` statements.
But I can not execute `match (v1)-[e:follow]->() return e limit N` statement, this will report error.

```
(root@nebula) [test_match]> match ()-[e:follow]->() return e limit 3 
+----------------------------------------------------+
| e                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| [:follow "player101"->"player100" @0 {degree: 95}] |
| [:follow "player101"->"player102" @0 {degree: 90}] |
| [:follow "player102"->"player100" @0 {degree: 75}] |
+----------------------------------------------------+
Got 3 rows (time spent 5216/6073 us)

Wed, 14 Dec 2022 07:09:11 UTC

(root@nebula) [test_match]> match ()-[e:follow]->(v2) return e limit 3 
+----------------------------------------------------+
| e                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| [:follow "player101"->"player100" @0 {degree: 95}] |
| [:follow "player101"->"player102" @0 {degree: 90}] |
| [:follow "player102"->"player100" @0 {degree: 75}] |
+----------------------------------------------------+
Got 3 rows (time spent 2752/3674 us)

Wed, 14 Dec 2022 07:09:15 UTC

(root@nebula) [test_match]> match (v1)-[e:follow]->() return e limit 3 
[ERROR (-1005)]: Scan vertices or edges need to specify a limit number, or limit number can not push down.
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587). Since you got an error message, you should include it in your question title following the guidance in [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running `MATCH (n:tag)-[e]-() RETURN n LIMIT 10`. From my experience, to return a limited number of edges without creating any index on that edge type, you can only use `()-[e:follow]->()` or `()-[e:follow]->(v2)`, but cannot use the pattern `(v1)-[e:follow]->()`, i.e., you cannot set a variable for the first vertex in the pattern.

Or you can simply create an index on the edge type, or any tag that shows up in the pattern.